# .Net Core how to implement SQLAdapter ./ DataTable function

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-core

I have a simple .Net Framework routine which runs a query and returns a DataTable object.  I need to port this to .Net Core, however I infer that SQLAdapter and DataTable are not supported

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
// assign the transaction and connection to the command object
cmd.Connection = con;
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// execute query and soak up results
sda.Fill(dt);
return dt;
```

Can anyone suggest how I can reimplement this code, using what is supported ?
Thanks

Comment: Well, you could start by looking at the reference source for [SqlDataAdapter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataAdapter.cs) and [DataTable](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs) and reimplement the parts you actually need... also: good luck.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but not sure how helpful that is.  I had assumed that many others would have hit this problem, and that they are not all setting out to fix it by implementing parts of the Framework.

Comment: Well, one problem is that if .Net Core does not know about `DataTable`, then you can't `return dt` and everything else that would work with the `DataTable` won't work anymore. So the question is, what functionality of the `DataTable` do you really need, and can you use for example a `DataReader` for that instead (if `DataReader` is available in .Net Core; never worked with that).

Comment: use either entityframework or dapper. for this

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier How can I get untyped query results from Dapper?

Answer (score 23):

`SqlDBAdapter` and `DataTable` are now supported.

You must use VS2017 Preview 15.3, target .net core 2.0, and add NuGet packages for `System.Data.Common` as well as `System.Data.SqlClient`. Code below.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/ for more info.

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(SqlConnection conn, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID");
    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName");
    SqlDataReader dr = ExecuteReader(conn, cmdType, cmdText, cmdParms);
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1]);
    }
    return dt;
}

public static DataTable ExecuteDataTableSqlDA(SqlConnection conn, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: I haven't used VS2017 Preview 15.3 yet so I was unaware of this development.

Comment: happy that this helped you out.

Comment: As of VS2017 Preview 15.4 this still requires the prerelease version of `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: Hi is there a way to do this with oracle DB ?

Comment: re oracle 
.NET Core and Entity Framework Statement of Direction - March 2018 - www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/odpnet-dotnet-ef-core-sod-4395108.pdf
ODP.NET Core Beta Download - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html
ODP.NET Discussion Forum - https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/odp.net

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE:** This answer corresponds to .NET Core 1.x (which was the latest at the time I wrote this).
If you are using .NET Core 2.x (in beta as of July/2017), check Joe's answer.

**Original answer:**

Recommended read: [Porting to .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/)

I quote:

> - **System.Data**. While the base layer is already part of .NET Core, i.e. the provider model and SQL client, some features are currently not available, such as schema support and DataTable/DataSet.

You can use SqlDataReader but not SqlAdapter or DataTable.

Start by adding `System.Data.SqlClient` NuGet Package.

Then you can...

```
var con = new SqlConnection("...");
var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "...";
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// populate your custom data structure
```

Does `IList<Dictionary<string, object>>` works for you?

```
var results = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    results.Add(Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).ToDictionary(reader.GetName, reader.GetValue));
}
return results;
```

So now you can read using `results[0]["FirstName"].ToString()`

Unless you want to switch to Entity Framework Core, in that case this [tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html) is handy.

Comment: Close but no cigar.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer. It's nice to know that it is supported now.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of DataAdapter/DataTable you may use one of the existing DAL libraries for .NET Core that support CRUD operations over low-level ADO.NET interfaces. Recently I've published [NReco.Data](https://github.com/nreco/data): provider-independent DAL that supports automatic SQL statements generation, abstract queries and simple record CRUD operations.

For example, code snippet from the question can be reimplemented in the following way:

```
var con = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectString);
var dbFactory = new NReco.Data.DbFactory(
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance);
var dbCmdBuilder = new NReco.Data.DbCommandBuilder(dbFactory);
var dbAdapter = new NReco.Data.DbDataAdapter(con, dbCmdBuilder);

var selectRecordsList = dbAdapter.Select( 
    new Query("some_table") ).ToList<Dictionary<string,object>>();
```

Complex SQL queries may be executed as application-level data views:

```
dbCmdBuilder.Views["some_view"] = new DbDataView(
    @"SELECT @columns FROM Employee emp
      LEFT JOIN Company c ON (c.Id=emp.CompanyId)
      @where[ WHERE {0}] @orderby[ ORDER BY {0}]
    ") {
      FieldMapping = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
        {"Id", "emp.Id"},
        {"*", "emp.*, c.Title as CompanyTitle"}
      }
    };
var someViewRS = dbAdapter.Select( new Query("some_view") ).ToRecordSet();
```

NReco.Data doesn't try to *replace* SQL with the its own Query (like LINQ does); instead of that it allows you to make simple DB-independent queries from business logic 
and encapsulate complex SQL syntax with special app-level dataviews that accessed like read-only tables.

Also it is possible to specify raw SQL query directly with `Select` method overload (like FromSql in EF Core):

```
var userModels = dbAdapter.Select("select * from users where id={0}", 5).ToList<User>();
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I have used DataReader and a lightweight data table (which is basically a Lists of Lists)

Comment: @Hughgo using DataReader is a simplest (and best-performance) solution of course :) I hope you'll try NReco.Data library on occasion. Don't hesitate to contact me in case of any questions or issues.

Comment: How on earth did you get such a project off the ground when your query objects are restricted to a named table? What about the literally millions of cases outside the playpen where a data source query might be dynamic sql, or a join, etc?

Comment: @ProfK Query is a generic structure that holds conditions and other options; it doesn't restricted to tables - you can specify database dataview or encapsulate complex SQL query (with JOINs, GROUP BY etc) as app-level dataview (see DbDataView class, it can be registered in DbCommandBuilder.Views). After all, you can provide raw SQL query like in EF Core or Dapper.

Comment: Thanks, @VitaliyFedorchenko, I wasn't away of that. An answer with a little example how to use raw SQL vs. a named DB artefact in a `Query` object will get you the bounty. I can't just make a named view for each query I may want to run.

Comment: @ProfK I've added code snippets that illustrate how to use app-level dataviews for complex SQL queries and raw SQL.

Comment: Thanks, @VitaliyFedorchenko. A few hours before I can give you the bounty, but otherwise it's yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DbDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter?view=netcore-3.1) link for more info

**Then use this function for CreateDataAdapter**

```
private static DbDataAdapter CreateDataAdapter(this DbConnection connection, DbCommand command)
{
     var adp = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connection).CreateDataAdapter();
     adp.SelectCommand = command;
     return adp;
 }
```

**Then normal can use like code below**

```
var connection = Context.Database.GetDbConnection();
using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = cmdText;
using DbDataAdapter adp = connection.CreateDataAdapter(command);
```

**After you can fill**

```
using DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(dataSet);
```

Comment: This is the best and fastest way provided directly in .NET API rather than using any third party nuget libraries or wout developing any extension methods.

Even simpler code :
`using (SqlConnection dbCD = new SqlConnection())
{
 dbCD.Open(); 
 using (SqlCommand cmd = dbCD.CreateCommand()) 
 { 
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableName"; 
 var adp = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dbCD).CreateDataAdapter(); 
 adp.SelectCommand = cmd; 
 adp.Fill(MyDataSets); 
 } 
dbCD.Close(); 
}`