# Iterating through a listbox and inserting its corresponding datagridview rows

Tags: c#

I have a `ListBox` named `lstEmployees` in which I assign a `DataSource` property to it. For the `DispalyMember` it gets the `EmployeeName` and for the `ValueMember` it gets the `Employee_ID`.

For each employee, there is a `List<DateTime>` that contains the login and logout entries. I have a `DataGridView` named `dgvLogRecords` in which I populate it with that list record by record.

I want to iterate through each employee in the `lstEmployees` and, if there are any log entries, I want to insert them into the database. The problem is, how do I go through each employee in the list while getting the `DataGridView` to respond to that particular employee each time?

Assume that the `DataGridView` has two columns: the `logtime` for the employee and the `logtype` (e.g logtype can be `in`, `out` or `unknown`). Each employee might have one, many, or no records at all.

The `DataGridView` looks somewhat like this:

```
logtime            | logtype
-------------------|--------
27/5/2017 7:30:00  | in
27/5/2017 14:45:00 | out
28/5/2017 8:59:13  | unknown
28/5/2017 14:45:00 | in
28/5/2017 22:10:03 | out
29/5/2017 13:00:15 | unkown
```

I have to iterate through the `DataGridView` for each employee, insert the `in` and `out` values using a specific function (`InsertCompleteRecord(Employee_Id, in, out)`), and insert the `unknown` record only if there was one at the very end of the `DataGridView` (using `InsertMissingRecord(Employee_Id, missing record)`).

Here's the code to where I stopped:

```
DataTable dt = Employee.GetActiveEmployeesSummary();
while (lstEmployees.Items.Count > 0) 
{
    lstEmployees.SelectedIndex = 0;
    if (dgvLogRecords.Rows.Count == 0) 
    {
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(lstEmployees.SelectedIndex);
        lstEmployees.DataSource = dt;
        lstEmployees.SelectedIndex = 0;
        continue;
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLogRecords.Rows)

    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(lstEmployees.SelectedIndex);
    lstEmployees.DataSource = dt;
    lstEmployees.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

The function `Employee.GetActiveEmployeesSummary()` is used for the `DataSource` so that I can delete employees from the `lstEmployees` after dealing with each employee's records.

Comment: Use the DataTable Accept changes method (dt.AcceptChanges()).  For the changes to work the Command to the database need to have four queries 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Insert 4) Update. So you can use a CommandBuilder.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I know how to deal with database using the command builder. In fact, I'm using a library called `IGUtility` for all sorts of database operations which works a bit differently from the built-in class (i.e the command builder).  I just can't get the proper data for my table in the database. Thanks though for taking from your time and answering me!

Comment: Read following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607883/net-core-how-to-implement-sqladapter-datatable-function

Comment: It looks like there's a little misunderstanding. Sir, I have no problem whatsoever with inserting, deleting or updating from/into the database. The problem I've encountered (as I have previously stated) is getting the specific values from the `DataGridView` which corresponds to the specific employee in the `lstEmployees` for all employees in the `ListBox`.